# Time taken to display output in postgres 9.1

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Does postgres include the time taken for rendering the output on screen within \timing or explain analyze. From what I understand it does not. Am I correct?

Actually I am outputting a lot of rows on screen and I find that postgres does not take much time to display them on screen, whereas if I write a simple C program to output the results, then the C programs takes about 3000ms. Whereas postgres takes about 500ms to display the same data on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"postgres" doesn't display anything at all. I think you mean the `psql` client.

If so: `\timing` displays time including the time to receive the data from the server. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` doesn't, but adds the overhead of doing the detailed server-side timing. `log_min_duration_statement` just records statement timings server-side.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please give an example illustrating the use of long_min statement duration. Also does long_min take into account the amount of time required to render the output on screen

Comment: @RoseBeck That should've been `log_min_duration_statement`. It's in the user manual.